# ParamSpec types PEP 612

Tags: python, type-hinting

With Python 3.11

Taking the example here, https://peps.python.org/pep-0612/#semantics

```py
P = ParamSpec("P")
U = TypeVar("U")

class Y(Generic[U, P]):
  f: Callable[P, str]
  prop: U

  def __init__(self, f: Callable[P, str], prop: U) -> None:
    self.f = f
    self.prop = prop

def a(q: int) -> str: ...

Y(a, 1)   # Should resolve to Y[(q: int), int]
Y(a, 1).f # Should resolve to (q: int) -> str
```

What is this type definition here? `Y[(q: int), int]`

`foo: Y[(q: int), int] = ...` gives a type error (naturally), so what is it?

Comment: The P is the type of the parameters, it's showing the parameter list of a. It's not actually valid syntax (nor is (q: int) -> str), just trying to show intent.

Comment: Yeah weird, it should just say unknown then instead of some wrong type hint.

Comment: It's not unknown, we know what it is. They're not _intended_ to be syntactically valid type hints; again it's just an attempt to illustrate what would happen. They could maybe have used `[int]` instead, but that's not quite right either as the function would also accept q as a _keyword_ argument (the difficulty representing this is part of the reason ParamSpec exists).

Comment: Is anything proposed like this? It would be good for specifying a more precise param spec